# Can I use a SanDisk 64GB microSDHC Extreme Plus Memory on a Canon 70D DSLR?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, sdcard

I bought this SD card at Walmart mistaking it for the SanDisk Extreme Pro  , the one sd card everyone uses on the Canon 70D, and well, I'm wondering if its campitable with the camera?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, but you'll need an adapter because micro-SD is smaller than a regular SD-card.

[image: Micro-SD half-inserted in an adapter]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a 64GB Micro SD Card, because the Maximum supported storage on the 70D is 64GB, you will need to use a micro SD card adapter in order to fit the card within the camera, speed will be no different to using an equivalent SD Card.

Comment: I would love to contribute to this StackExchange site, and it would help me out if I can use the odd link to my website, however would like to know the correct way of doing this so my links are not removed like last time

Comment: I think the most important thing is to be an active member and not ONLY answer questions that you can use as an excuse for link building. So welcome along and join in :-)

Comment: Thank you, I would love to be a regular contributor here :)

Comment: Hey @specced.  I went ahead and removed the link on this one as well.  The main reason was that it didn't really meaningfully add to the answer.  Generally, external links are best when a) clearly disclosed, b) a minor portion of overall contributions and c) offer additional relevant detail beyond what can be covered in a single answer.  A good example of this would be if someone wanted to know the major differences between two cameras and linking to the comparison would allow them to see all the differences after answering the major points directly in the answer.  Relevance is key.

Comment: If you want more assistance with trying to figure out when it is and isn't appropriate, feel free to hop in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat) some time to ask for more clarification.  I know it can be tricky to figure out where the proper balance is and where it is and isn't appropriate.